# transaction (s) not going through due to low fees selected

Tags: transactions, transaction-fees, unconfirmed-transactions

I'm having a problem with a bitcoin transaction (not through btcpay, but i don't know where else to turn to). I sent 0.06btc from my wallet to my father (20 hours ago), and stupid as i am, decided to be a cheap bastard and chose the smallest fees. The transaction hasn't gone through and i don't know what todo...

https://bitpay.com/insight/#/BTC/mainnet/tx/ea3536f6fc340a722633525eae720f2814da563fd3ca757c2736e2c92158327f

about 4/5 hours ago, my father activated the option from his side saying he would pay the necessary fees (so he says)  but still nothing happens...
Extra info: my wallet is Copay on iPhone and he's using Bitpay on android phone...

Please help me get my mind at ease, what is supposed to happen here? and in what time frame?

much appreciated for any information, even if it's just instruction on where else to go ask this...

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Your tx seems okay now (3 confirmations when I wrote this answer): [BlockChair explorer](https://blockchair.com/bitcoin/transaction/ea3536f6fc340a722633525eae720f2814da563fd3ca757c2736e2c92158327f)

Next time before resorting to paid service, you can try free BTC Accelerator such as BitAccelerate.

Comment: -1 According to BitAccelerate's website, this "free accelerator" merely rebroadcasts stuck transactions upon submission. Since a transaction is already broadcast to all users when its submitted to the network, this would only help resubmit the transaction if the transaction got evicted in a mempool overflow, which can be done through a lot of blockexplorers already. It is unclear why rebroadcasting should help getting a quicker confirmation, and them alluding to that in conjunction with asking for donation makes the website sound scammy to me.

Comment: A mining pool may drop your transaction when its behind on the mempool. In this case, rebroadcasting actually helps. Asking for donation for free service doesn't make it scammy. Scammy is a site that doesn't do anything yet asking for a fee 

https://en.bitcoin.it/wiki/Transaction_accelerator

Comment: I had already mentioned the mempool eviction. Anyway, even the page you link states the same: "are not actually helping to get a transaction confirmed faster".